# Re-distributing ethernet through wireless

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, bridge, ubuntu-12.10

I'm looking to re-broadcast a wired network that normally goes through a router through my PC on it's wireless card. I'm running Win 7 Ultimate or Ubuntu 12.10, I have dual boot. I can bridge the connections in Windows, but it's not actually rebroadcasting the network. Ad-hoc connections allow for a connection through, but I'm looking to send out the ORIGINAL network. How do I go about this?

Edit: Ah, figured out how to phrase it better. There is a wired network that normally goes through a wireless router. Basically, I want to temporarily replace the router with my wireless card, making it behave like the original router.

Comment: I have read your post several times, and cannot make out what you are asking. could you please clarify?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to take a wired ethernet connection and broadcast it as a WiFi connection, right? Connectify Hotspot (including the free edition) can do this, but I'm not sure what you mean by "send out the original network". I'm not aware of any way to have everything be on the same network when re-sharing via a WiFi card.